# What is the best practice to use Bootstrap's modals with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootstrap-modal

It's a minor question, but here's the thing, I have this dynamic list of news in my webpage, when you click a link it opens a modal with a title and a paragraph.

At the moment I'm thinking that since the number of links will always be small -like 6 at most-, I could write JS that would write the actual DOM and put all the required classes on the page before running bootstrap. Meaning that the browser would have to load all the text information when it reaches the page.

But if the content was a little bigger, I feel that it would be better to load the news dinamically, meaning that I'd have to attach a function to each link that would change the content of the modal before showing it to the user.

Does it make a difference? Is there a better practice? Does it really matter?

Comment: This is a good example of a question that's primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Meaning that there is not a standard practice? Or that it really doesn't matter?

Comment: Not enough known, SEO considerations for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would load it dynamically to make sure its efficient if you decide to make the data larger in the future. But as of now it won't really make a difference in speed.